# How to reference another file within frontmatter of an .md file?

Tags: javascript, markdown, astrojs

I'm setting up Astro [Content Collections](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/content-collections/), and I would like to reference a specific author from my `authorCollection` within an article.

I thought I could do something similar to this in the frontmatter of my article:

```
--- 

title: My Article 

author: [John Doe](./authors/author-john-doe.md)

---
```

If the above is possible, how should I define it in the config file?

This is my current `articleCollection` definition:

```
const articleCollection = defineCollection({
  schema: z.object({
    title: z.string(),
    publishedAt: z.date(),
    updatedAt: z.date(),
    excerpt: z.string(),
    seoDescription: z.string(),
    category: z.array(z.string()),
    image: z.string().optional(),
    author: z.string().default("Anonymous"),
  }),
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make the `author` property an object and reference it accordingly when querying the collection.

Your article would be:

```
---
title: My Article
author:
    name: John
    link: './authors/author-john'
---

Article content
```

Your schema definition would be:

```
import { defineCollection, z } from 'astro:content';

const articleCollection = defineCollection({
    schema: z.object({
        title: z.string(),
        author: z.object({
            name: z.string(),
            link: z.string()
        }).optional().default({
            name: 'Anonymous',
            link: './authors/author-anonymous'
        })
        // Other properties
    }),
});

export const collections = {
    articles: articleCollection,
};
```

Querying the collection from your Astro component:

```
---
import { getCollection } from 'astro:content';
const allArticles = await getCollection('articles');
---

<ul>
    {allArticles.map(article => (
        <li>
            <h1>{article.data.title}</h1>
            <a href={article.data.author.link}>{article.data.author.name}</a>
        </li>
    ))}
</ul>
```

**NOTE:** To make sure that links to specific authors will be accessible, you need to configure [dynamic routing](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/routing/#dynamic-routes) for each author page.